# @NotNull annotation is not working in Spring boot application

Tags: java, spring, spring-boot, spring-mvc

Below is my DTO class.

```
public class AbstractDTO extends BaseDTO {

    private Integer createdBy;

    @JsonFormat(shape = JsonFormat.Shape.STRING, pattern = DATE_FORMAT)
    @NotNull(message = "createdDate may not be null")
    private LocalDateTime createdDate;

    private Integer lastModifiedBy;
    @JsonFormat(shape = JsonFormat.Shape.STRING, pattern = DATE_FORMAT)
    private LocalDateTime lastModifiedDate;

    private Boolean isActive;

    // getter & setters
}
```

Here I am trying to annotate createdDate field as @NotNull but is it not working. It is allowing in request body and after executing the service in postman not getting any error.

I have tried below options but no luck.

**1) Tried to add maven dependency.**

```
<dependency>
    <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
    <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-validation</artifactId>
</dependency>
```

**2) Tried to annotate DTO class as @Validated**

**3) Tried to annotate createdDate field @Valid with @NotNull but still not luck.**

Please help me out with this issue.

Comment: Did you try to annotate the DTO class as @Validated in the controller method signature ? something like `void foo(@Validated MyDTO dto)`

Comment: @ArnaudDenoyelle This DTO has been used in multiple location more than 25 files, Do I have to make changes in every file? Is there any other solution?

Comment: Does you app has starter - spring-boot-starter-web which will load hibernate Validator to dependency. Which will validate the bean. Please go through this link - https://stackoverflow.com/questions/48200444/spring-validation-vs-hibernate-validation?rq=1

Comment: Check my answer, it should resolve your issue. But if `@NotNull` does not work while `@JsonPattern` works, then it might be the case with the wrong `@NotNull` being used. Otherwise it seems you forgot adding `@Valid` on your controller method.

Answer (score 19):

Your DTO class is correct. You have to use `@Valid` annotation.

For example :

```
@Controller
public class Controller {

    @PostMapping("/")
    public String checkPersonInfo(@Valid AbstractDTO abstractDTO, BindingResult bindingResult) {

        if (bindingResult.hasErrors()) {
            return "some-page";
        }
        return "some-other-page";
    }
}
```

**Refer to this [Spring Boot Example On Validating Form Input](https://spring.io/guides/gs/validating-form-input/)  for reference.**

Why to use `@Valid` annotation ?

*This allows you to validate the set of constraints applied on the data members of a class.*

---

*However, if you have XML based configuration in your project, then you have to add this below in the **applicationContext.xml** given below. (Source : [here](https://developer.ucsd.edu/develop/data-layer/jpa/java-validation-api.html))*

```
<bean
    class="org.springframework.web.servlet.mvc.annotation.AnnotationMethodHandlerAdapter">
    <property name="webBindingInitializer">
        <bean
            class="org.springframework.web.bind.support.ConfigurableWebBindingInitializer">
            <property name="validator" ref="validator" />
        </bean>
    </property>
</bean> 

    <bean id="validator"
        class="org.springframework.validation.beanvalidation.LocalValidatorFactoryBean">
    </bean>
```

Answer (score 9):

You have an endpoint with some request body like;

```
@RestController
public class TheController {

    @PostMapping(path = "/doSomething", consumes = "application/json", produces = "application/json")
    public void post(@Valid @RequestBody AbstractDTO request) {
        //code
    }
}
```

You need to have `@Valid` annotation for the request object. Only with this you'd have validation enabled for `AbstractDTO` for `/doSomething` endpoint.

Check [here](https://www.baeldung.com/spring-boot-bean-validation), for more in depth details

Answer (score 5):

Have you got the right import ?
I use `import javax.validation.constraints.NotNull;`

Answer (score 3):

**Description**

1. In my case, I define 1 parent class A has 3 sub class B, C, D such as:

> public A {   private B bCommand;   private C cCommand;   private D
> dCommand; }

2. I annotated @NotNull, @NotBlank for some fields in 3 sub class.
   In Controller, I have put @Valid for function like that:

> @PostMapping() public ResponseEntity create(@RequestBody @Valid A
> command){ }

**Solution**

1. I put @Valid for sub class which has field(s) need to check constraint.
2. Example:
   Class B, C have some fields which have constraint like not null

> public A {  @Valid   private B bCommand;  @Valid   private C cCommand;
> private D dCommand; }